# JsonDeserializer failing to deserialize object

Tags: android, gson, json

I have started to test an application on Honeycomb and get the following error message:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter@408424f0 failed to deserialized json object
[{"type":"location","id":1,"name":"Manukau Heights","description":null,"children":[]},{"type":"location","id":2,"name":"Manukau Central","description":null,"children":[]},{"type":"location","id":3,"name":"Manukau City","description":null,"children":[]},{"type":"location","id":4,"name":"Redoubt North","description":null,"children":[]},{"type":"location","id":5,"name":"Redoubt South","description":null,"children":[]},{"type":"location","id":6,"name":"Goodwood Heights","description":null,"children":[]},{"type":"location","id":7,"name":"Totara Heights","description":null,"children":[]},{"type":"location","id":8,"name":"Totara Park","description":null,"children":[]}]
given the type com.google.gson.ParameterizedTypeImpl@8a7527
```

when using Gson and fromJson

```
MyLocation[] locations = gson.fromJson(in, MyLocation[].class);
```

MyLocation looks like this:

```
private String name = "";
private String type = "";
private String id;
private List<MyLocation> children = new ArrayList<MyLocation>();
private String description = "";
```

The main concern I have is that this works perfectly on many devices pre Honeycomb. I have tried with the following:
Nexus 1 2.3.4, 
HTC Hero 2.1 update 1, 
Dell Venue 2.2.2, 
Dell Streak 7" 2.2.2, 
Garmin Asus 2.1 update 1

and I see no Exceptions (and the data is imported seemingly perfectly).

Can anyone give advice what might be different and how I can manage it?

(I had a similar issue with XML being parsed differently but I managed a workaround for this going to Honeycomb)

Regards,
Julius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to using Jackson and this problem has gone away.  So this doesn't explain the original issue, but seems to work.

Comment: they are supposed to be exactly the the same, you should file a bug report.